# Finding the similarity between two functions

Tags: similarities, genetic-algorithms, function, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am a first-year grad student in Computer Science, and I need some help with a problem that I think is statistically oriented. I have taken a statistics course, but it was abysmal and I haven't had time to rectify that. But anyway, my problem stems from a project I'm working on involving genetic programming, where I'm randomly generating functions. Please bear with my description, as it's been a while since I've had a formal theory course too.

I have two continuous (but not onto) functions **F** and **G**, both of which map **N** variables to a single output. The domain of the input variables is the integers between -100 and 100. The range of the output is the Real numbers. I want to find some statistical measure of how "similar" the two functions are; given the finite inputs (of which there will be 201^N possible), how much variance(?) there is between the two functions outputs. Two identical functions should return no variance, and two wildly different functions should return a high variance.

Since **N** will typically be greater than 6, I can't iterate through all the possible inputs and compare the outputs, so I figured I could take some sampling at regular intervals (e.g. every multiple of 10, so that it's only 10^N). But here's about where I realize I have no idea what I'm doing. How do I determine if two numbers are "highly variant" from each other? What sample size do I need to use to have confidence in my results?

My current approach is to compare the functions with a two-sided Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test. Since that test doesn't seem to scale well to multi-variate problems, I've taken advantage of my limited domains to just treat the problem as having a single variable by concatenating my variables. So the first value of the variable is (-100:100:100:100:100:100), the second is (-100:100:100:100:100:099), and the last is (100:100:100:100:100:100). Does that even make sense?

Comment: Would something like summing the squares of the differences between F and G (or the absolute value of their differences) over all the values for which you have outputs for both suffice as a measure? With 6+ dimensions, I'd suggest not using a lattice-type grid of values, by the way, but random draws from the space of values (though you might use quasi-random sequences instead I suppose).

Comment: Have you considered Kullback-Leibler and Bhattacharya distances?

Answer (score -1):

Calculate a correlation of two functions over a set of random examples. The two-sided Kolmogorov-Smirnov test compares one-dimensional distributions, not multidimensional functions.

Comment: Correlation is useless for this purpose, even with single-predictors. Consider X on 1,2,3,4,5 and fits f and g being (12, 15, 17, 19, 23) and (101.12, 101.15, 101.17, 101.19 and 101.23) respectively. They're *perfectly* correlated, but they're nowhere near each other.

Comment: acbart writes: _I want to find some statistical measure of how "similar" the two functions are_.  The two functions are "similar".